# Quasar V2 attempting to have LeftDrawer closed on base closed, and hamburger button will open it

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I am seeking assistance with Quasar, I am completely new to coding and JS/Quasar framework. I was wondering if the out of box qdrawer can be tweaked so when launching the page, instead of having it opened by default, to have it closed instead and clicking the hamburger button will open it.

Mainlayout.vue:

```
<q-drawer v-model="leftDrawerOpen" show-if-above bordered>  <---- In question
  <q-list>
    <q-item-label header> Essential List </q-item-label>

    <EssentialLink
      v-for="link in essentialLinks"
      :key="link.title"
      v-bind="link"
    />
  </q-list>
</q-drawer>

<q-page-container>
  <router-view />
</q-page-container>
```

I attempted to rename to leftDrawerClosed but no success

Comment: the v-model determines the drawer's shown/hidden state.  if `leftDrawerOpen` is initialized as false, the drawer should initialize as hidden.  you can have anything you want (like a hamburger button) open the drawer given you add a [click event listener](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#listening-to-events) to it that sets `leftDrawerOpen` to true

Answer (score 1):

The element `q-drawer` uses several mechanisms to be opened or closed. First and foremost the binding to the variable `leftDrawerOpen` is essential. You may consider initializing it to `false` in the `setup` section. However, as the `q-drawer` element also contains the `show-if-above` directive, you should be aware that the state of this variable is ignored for larger screens (see the API docs: https://quasar.dev/layout/drawer). If the drawer should be closed regardless of screen size you should in addition remove this directive.